# ggplot2:histogram with condition

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I want to graph a histogram for my data. I 'm strugling with two issues.

First , how to separate the bars (frequency) for each break value. In other words, I have set breaks for X-axis in a log scale and I want to graph only for these breaks.... I don't want continues histogram bars (next each other), I want gaps between them....

Second, I 'm wondering how to apply condition to breaks. For example I have breaks=c(0.1,0.2,0.5,1,2,5,10,30,40), how to add one break as a condition something like breaks=c(0.1,0.2,0.5,1,2,5,10,30,40, "any value > 40").

Here is my data:

```
structure(list(Time = c(0.08618, 0.086591, 0.086752, 0.18448, 
0.093463, 0.092634, 0.087419, 0.087307, 0.085734, 0.085272, 0.18448, 
0.085154, 0.085021, 0.084936, 0.091301, 0.177737, 0.18448, 0.089677, 
0.084906, 0.08614, 0.194328, 0.10183, 0.086494, 0.088581, 0.089195, 
0.089914, 0.090335, 0.086295, 0.086589, 0.10714, 0.265871, 0.315305, 
0.251465, 0.167559, 0.828143, 0.19883, 0.16173, 0.297092, 0.199025, 
0.196639, 0.20123, 0.206766, 0.205378, 0.490892, 0.226212, 11.197049, 
3.215287, 0.201566, 8.732194, 1.890716, 0.589986, 15.215162, 
0.196188, 0.219697, 9.816025, 0.290359, 0.233825, 3.230766, 4.605698, 
0.804751, 0.41611, 0.51733, 9.318433, 0.812274, 0.41187, 9.843202, 
0.607423, 0.823639, 932, 0.243041, 0.309908, 929, 0.70039, 0.706538, 
9.848918, 0.427812, 2.213476, 923, 3.428199, 921, 6.247575, 1.007718, 
918, 0.628396, 0.156748, 800, 914, 900, 890, 850, 650)), .Names = "Time", row.names = c(NA, 
-91L), class = "data.frame")
```

here is my code:

```
 ggplot(DF, aes(x =Time))+
 geom_histogram(bin=0.1,position = "dodge", colour = "black", fill = "white")+
 scale_x_log10(breaks=c(0.1,0.2,0.5,1,2,5,10,20,30,40),expand=c(0.005,0.1))+
 scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0.04,0.3))
```

Below is what I'm getting...

[image]

Update: I want get something like :
[image]

I know this is bar-plot... However, I got this plot from excel where it automatically calculates the histogram for a range of bins. I was looking to do the whole thing in ggplot...
Any suggestions!!!

Comment: If you want gaps you need to use geom_bar instead, and that will require you to calculate the bins and the counts manually.

Comment: I got the graph that I want in Excel, was hoping to get it in ggplot2 !! Excel does the manual count.

Comment: If you post an image of you Excel graph I can see if I can re-create it using ggplot.

Comment: Basically, if you use excel, it allows you to set range of bins and counts the frequency for each bin. Graphing the results from the excel in ggplot would be simple. I was hoping to do it all in ggplot instead of taking the results from excel and do bar plot in ggplot. I guess no other option!! unless there is a way for setting a range of bins which I'm not aware of !!

Comment: It would be much easier if you just posted an image of the plot you want to create.

Comment: Thank.. I think the only way to do it in ggplot is to copy the calculated histogram data from Excel and use bar plot in ggplot. Se my update.

Comment: I've posted how you can do this in ggplot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This using your original breaks. I just calculated the counts manually.

```
brks<-c(0.1,0.2,0.5,1,2,5,10,30,40,"more")

count<-rep(1,10)
count[1]<-length(DF[which(DF$Time<=0.1),])
count[2]<-length(DF[which(DF$Time>0.1 & DF$Time<=0.2),])
count[3]<-length(DF[which(DF$Time>0.2 & DF$Time<=0.5),])
count[4]<-length(DF[which(DF$Time>0.5 & DF$Time<=1),])
count[5]<-length(DF[which(DF$Time>1 & DF$Time<=2),])
count[6]<-length(DF[which(DF$Time>2 & DF$Time<=5),])
count[7]<-length(DF[which(DF$Time>5 & DF$Time<=10),])
count[8]<-length(DF[which(DF$Time>10 & DF$Time<=30),])
count[9]<-length(DF[which(DF$Time>30 & DF$Time<=40),])
count[10]<-length(DF[which(DF$Time>40),])

data<-data.frame("breaks"=brks,"count"=count)

ggplot(data,aes(x=breaks,y=count))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c(0.1,0.2,0.5,1,2,5,10,30,40,"more"))
```

[image]

EDIT: Here's the plot with all of the options from your first attempt:

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=breaks,y=count))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",colour = "black",fill = "white")+
  scale_x_log10(breaks=c(0.1,0.2,0.5,1,2,5,10,30,40,600),
                labels = c("0.1","0.2","0.5","1","2","5","10","30","40","> 600"),
                expand=c(0.005,0.1))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0.04,0.3))
```

[image]

EDIT2: Wider plot to put distance between 30 and 40

[image]

Comment: Perfect.. But why the X-axis is not ordered (i.e. 1,10,2,30,40,5 )..Do we need to use 'reorder' or something !!

Comment: Ya, I noticed that after I posted it. I edited it and fixed it. I can also do this on a log scale if you want, and with the other options you set in ggplot in your original post.

Comment: Thank you very much....Is it possible to control the space between breaks label (i.e. 30-40).

Comment: You can make the plot wider, but to change it any other way would be to no longer have a logarithmic x-axis. See edit with wider plot.

Comment: You could also have the last bar at something smaller like >100. The reason I have it as >600 was for accuracy. The values in that count are all 650 and greater.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't have gaps between the bar of a histogram in `ggplot2`.

For your second question, this code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Time))+
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.1, colour = "black", fill = "white")+
  scale_x_log10(breaks = c(0.1,0.2,0.5,1,2,5,10,20,30,40,100),
                labels = c("0.1","0.2","0.5","1","2","5","10","20","30","40","> 100"),
                expand = c(0.005,0.1))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.04,0.3))
```

gives this result:
[image]

Comment: Was hoping to get it in ggplot2 (did it in Excel), thanks for the second part. Are you aware for another way other than label. I want the last two bars to be on ">100" label.